# Copying string into an array and then printing it using for loop

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have been trying to create a program where you can input text into a `char` array. The program does compile, however when I run the program it prints a weird question mark character without end.

```
int main()
    {
    char array[20];    
    int arraynumber;    
    scanf("%c", &array);    
    for(arraynumber = 0; arraynumber = 19; arraynumber++){    
        printf("%c", array[arraynumber]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", &array);` --> `scanf("%19s", array);`  (Read a string)

Comment: `arraynumber = 19` (assign 19 to `arraynumber`) doesn't make sense as your loop's test expression.  Also, you're only scanning one char...

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and use a recent (i.e. design frozen more than ca. 10 years ago) compiler. You should get warnings. Do not ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char array[20];
    int arraynumber;
    for (arraynumber = 0; arraynumber < 20; arraynumber++){
        scanf("%c", &array[arraynumber]);
    }
    for(arraynumber = 0; arraynumber < 20; arraynumber++){
        printf("%c", array[arraynumber]);
    }
}
```

Couple of problems:
1. You only read one character
2. Your for loop termination is wrong

See corrected code

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1. change from scanf("%c", &array) to scanf("%s", &array)
2. to work as a correctly "for-loop" u have to run it 20 times, i.e. 0-19.
   Change ur for loop to that: for(arraynumber = 0; arraynumber <= 19; arraynumber++)